# What is the correct term for a non-constant upper or lower bound?

Tags: real-analysis, terminology, upper-lower-bounds

In analysis, we often compute lower and upper estimates for a quantity.  Sometimes these are called *lower (or upper) bounds*, but that seems incorrect, as a *bound* in analysis refers to a constant.

Calling them *estimates* is misleading as well: The significance of a lower "estimate" is not that it approximates the quantity (it may be very far off!), only that it is *always less than* the quantity, a property which "estimates" do not have.

What is the correct term, then, for non-constant lower (or upper) estimates/bounds?

Comment: A bound is something a bounds something. There is absolutely no need for a bound to be constant.

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez: Indeed, a rather infamous mathematician's Ph.D. dissertation title uses the term ["boundary functions"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22boundary+functions%22+%22unabomber%22&filter=0), and the term appears in all but perhaps a couple of his papers. However, in this case [the term is being used as a precise liminf/limsup bound](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22boundary+function%22+semicontinuous) (sometimes modified to ignore countable sets or measure zero sets). Also "boundary functions" in PDEs, but here the usage is analogous to an initial condition.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez When we say "set A is bounded" don't we mean "bounded by a constant"? Or does _bounded_ mean something different for sets than functions?

Comment: If any moment you are using a word and feel there is even the slightest margin for confusion, be explicit about what you mean. That is the only rule.

Answer (score 1):

You can say the quantity of interest is bounded above (resp. below) by the function $f(x),$ for example.